# why is conditional rendering not working for form input in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-rendering

I have a form with select options :

```
        <div>
            <select>
                <option v-model="department" :value="n" v-for="n in ['Please select', 'Medicine', 'Dental']">{{n}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="alignBtn">
            <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="generateSlip()" value="Submit" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

and based on the selection in the above I want to display header content:

```
               <div v-if="{department} === 'Medicine'">
                    <h1>Option A</h1>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <h1>Option B</h1>
                </div>
```

but every time Option B is getting outputted .

Comment: Is there any special reason for using '{}' around 'department' in `v-if`

Comment: you mean just `department` should render the value of department ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `v-model` directive should be in the `select` element. You probably meant to do this ..

```
<div>
    <select v-model="department">
        <option :value="n" v-for="n in ['Please select', 'Medicine', 'Dental']">{{n}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="alignBtn">
    <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="generateSlip()" value="Submit" />
    </label>
</div>
```

You also don't need destructuring in this case. So you can use `department` in your equality comparison directly ..

```
<div v-if="department === 'Medicine'">
    <h1>Option A</h1>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <h1>Option B</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, make sense thanks, can you also help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53902123/3311276 please

Comment: Also you don't need strict comparison here.